# texto sobrepuesto html y css en templates de correos electronicos en outlook

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Estoy usando vue.js para la visualizacion del correo con una platilla html y css

Realize un template mandando una variable y con HTML y css lo acomode, Outlook web lo puedo ver de manera correcta pero Outlook desktop me manda la imagen y abajo el texto de la variable.

````
export class MailStandar {
   mail(titulo,Content) {
     const maill = `<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;"><tr><td bgcolor=black  style='background-image: url("https:imagen.png")';background-repeat:repeat-x; width='800' height='170'><p style='color: white; font-size: 50px; font-weight: bold; width: 570px;'>`+titulo+`</p></td></tr> <tr><td style="text-align: center; padding: 5%;"><p style="color: black;">`+Content+`</p></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:center"><hr style="border: none; border-top: 1px solid #ddd; margin: 30px auto;"><p style="color: #5b5b5b; font-size: 16px; margin: 0;">ejemplo1.1</p><div style="background-color: #5b5b5b; padding: 5px;"><p style="color: white; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; text-align:center">Si requieres enviar un comunicado por favor solicítalo a <b><a href="#" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;">Comunicación Interna.</a></b> ¡El cumplimiento de nuestras políticas es responsabilidad de todos!</p></div> </td> </tr></table> `;
     return maill;
   }
 } ```
````

Comment: Trata de dejar una medida fija para la table, usualmente uso 600px width en mis proyectos, una herramienta util para esto tambien es usa mailchimp u otra herramienta para que te genere la plantilla y luego solo la importas

Comment: muchas gracias @AugustoM

Comment: solo que en outloock descktop no me respeta los estilos de texto ensima de un backgraound

Comment: Debes revisar tus clases, por ejemplo los media queries no se pueden utilizar, y generalmente las reglas que se pueden aplicar son aquellas que pueden aplicar en linea con el atributo style dentro del elemento de HTML

Comment: Para outlook creo que habia que agregar unas etiquetas como: <!--[if gte mso 9]> y cerrarla con: <![endif]-->, el mailchimp ya te hace esto

Comment: claro son tablas fantasmas yo tengo  mso16 por mi version pero aun asi no funciona lo del puro texto dentro del background image los estilos si los manda bien colores tamaños imagenes menos el texto sobre mi imagen